# signup to Laravel from a different server

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-5.3, csrf

I want to show a signup form on a website but then when user hits submit, the form data will be posted to a Laravel app (on a different server) for registration.

So far, laravel stops it throwing the CSRF not found exception. Any idea how to work around it ?

Comment: Ignore the crsf token on your login page, add `/login` to the `except` array in your `Http/Middleware/VerifyCrsfToken.php` Please be aware that there is a reason for the CRSF tokens and this might help gain unwanted people easier access to your site.

Comment: what about creating an API for registration and calling that API from the site.... check this for API guidance https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/rest-api-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both applications are yours?

You can create a new middleware group:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
    ],

    'remote-login' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

Commenting/removing/disabling the VerifyCsrfToken middleware. Then map it to a new file:

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

    Route::middleware('remote-login')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/remote-login.php'));
}
```

Then in your `routes/remote-login.php`, you better create a non-trivial login route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'remote-login'], function () {
    Route::get('/auth/8g7h6jk5l4oA/', function () {
        dd('do you authentication');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Antonio's approach will work, but it's easier to just add the routes you don't want protected by the CSRF middleware to the `$except` array in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`.